# How to access context variables in parents template django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have `base.html` and file with header `_header_main.html` in my main template `index.html` i extends `base.html` and include `_header_main.html` but variables that i pass into `index.html` not visible in parent template

**base.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <!-- styles -->
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block _header_main %}{% endblock %}
        {% block _header_mobile %}{% endblock %}
        <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- header -->
        {% block header_main %}{% endblock %}
        {% block header_mobile %}{% endblock %}

        <div class="after_header"></div>
    <!-- end header -->
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <footer class="footer">
            ...
        </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**_header_main.html:**

```
<header class="header">
    <ul>
    {% for i in servers %}
        <li>{{ i.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</header>
```

**index.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block header_main %}
    {% include "_header_main.html" %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    Some content...
{% endblock %}
<scripts>
...
</scripts>
```

How i can access to variables `items` in my template?

**Edit. My function in views.py**

```
def index(request):
    servers = Server.objects.all().order_by('ranking')
    basket_count, total_price = basket_calculate(request)
    server_arr = [i.title for i in servers]
    servers_string = ', '.join(server_arr)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'servers':servers, 'temp_year' : datetime.now().year,
                                          'basket_count':basket_count, 'total_price':total_price,
                                          'servers_string':servers_string })
```

Comment: Please show your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why my `items` variable don't show in templates, is because i add `<script>` tag with `js` without block, so my scripts didn't work. I add my scripts to `{% block script %}` and all works fine!